# Swift Loading a View from a XIB

Tags: xcode, swift, view, xib

I have been following this tutorial in order to load a xib at the push of a button in a view controller:
http://www.thomashanning.com/loading-a-view-from-a-xib/

At this line:

```
if let customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? CustomView {
```

I get the below error:
***Use of undeclared type 'CustomView'***

I have followed the tutorial every step several times and I do not know what I am missing. Can anybody help with an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Tha would be obvious yes. But I did...

Comment: Select your CustomView.swift file and check in Xcode's information panel that its target box is correctly checked, maybe it doesn't target properly.

Comment: at target membership it's my project name and it is selected

Comment: And the file where you write `if let customView ...` and get this error also has the same target?

Comment: checked and yes, it has the same target. any more ideas? happy to try anything

Comment: Nope, sorry, no more ideas. I hope someone else will find. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Idan This is what I told OP in my first comment, but apparently they did create the class.

Comment: Just tried the tutorial, aside for constraints errors, it is working fine. Notice that the tutorial skips few steps, like the file & how to connect the outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your detailed answers, unfortunately none of them were of help.

There was not anything logic in what was happening, as I was not able to create any new classes of any type and call them without error.

So after many hours of frustration **I created a new project, dragged all my old files in it(except plist) and after a run I was able to create new classes and create instances of them without errors.**

Answer (score 2):

The error indicate that you missed a step declaring the class

> Use of undeclared type 'CustomView'

One of few things could be missed:

1. You didn't create the `CustomView.swift` file, the tutorial skipped this part. That file should contine the following:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CustomView: UIView {
     @IBAction func ButtonDidPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
       print("Button Pressed")
     }
   }
   ```

   Corresponding error (in editor):

   > Use of undeclared type 'CustomView'
2. In Storyboard `Identity Inspector` you didn't set the class name correctly.

   Corresponding error (in run time):

   > Unknown class CustomView in Interface Builder file.
3. Your class declaration is not identical to the call, but I think you should be able to identify this situation in `Xcode` editor.

   Corresponding error (in editor):

   > Use of undeclared type 'CustomView'

Comment: Great analysis , in first time I was thinking to set File's Owner to CustomView

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have went through all you points and none of them helped out yet. There seems to be a problem with any new class created. I can not call an instance of it, only instances of old classes I created.

Comment: Here is the working project. Try and compare. I didn't tried and fix the constrains, but otherwise followed the tutorial. link.https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15024098/example.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way give same name for UIView class and View/.Xib also

[image: You can use this way give same name for UIView class and View/.Xib also]

```
let alert = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("PromotionMenu", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? PromotionMenu
        alert?.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(alert!)
```